# Flutter DropdownButton inside TextFormField as prefix

Tags: flutter

As per title, I want to add a `DropdownButton` inside a `TextFormField` as `prefix` (or `prefixIcon`?). The text field is for amount, and the dropdown is for its currency.

My straightforward approach works visually, but I can't tap the dropdown to show the list. Every time I tap it, it will show (and immediately hide) the keyboard for the text field itself.

How to do it?

```
TextFormField(
    initialValue: '10.00',
    decoration: InputDecoration(
        prefix: DropdownButtonHideUnderline(
            child: DropdownButton(
                items: CURRENCY_CODES,
                onChanged: _onCurrencyChanged,
                value: _currency,
            ),
        ),
    ),
),
```

Comment: Could you post the code with the approach you're taking?

Comment: Have you tried to use two separate widgets wrapping them with `Row`? I don't think that `prefix` can be used with `DropdownButton`. According to the documentation, `prefix can be used, for example, to add some padding to text that would otherwise be specified using prefixText, or to add a custom widget in front of the input.`

Comment: @PabloBarrera question updated.

Comment: @Marat I customize the text field to be rounded with shadow, so I prefer to put everything inside.

Comment: [You can check this answer if this help.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76825479/20648449)

[Signup Page][1]

[Text Field when focused dropdown appears][2]

[Selected item updated in TextField][3]

  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/N6CBB.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SJPS8.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeiRZ.png

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**The Problem**

When you tap on the `Widget` contained on `prefix`, the `TextFormField` will focus and the keyboard will appear. But since the `Widget` is a `DropdownButton`, when the `DropdownItems` are shown the keyboard is dismissed and strangely the `DropdownItems` are dismissed too.

If you try to use `PopupMenuButton` instead of `DropdownButton`, something similar happens: the keyboard is shown and then dismissed but in this case the `PopupMenuItems` aren't dismissed. For this I could have a workaround using focus listeners and flags, but is not good.

---

**The Solution**

Take another approach, one way could be to use a `Container` with the decoration you want, wrapping a `Row` that contains a `DropdownButton` / `PopupMenuButton` and the `TextFormField`.

---

**The Implementation**

If you go with a `DropdownButton`, when you focus the `TextFormField` and then you tap the `DropdownButton`, the keyboard will be dismissed and strangely the `DropdownItems` are dismissed too. This is an unresolved issue: [DropdownButton bad behaviour when tapped and keyboard is showing](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/22075)

If you go with a `PopupMenuButton`, you could do something like this:

```
Wrap(
  children: <Widget>[
    Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        color: Colors.white,
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
        boxShadow: [BoxShadow()],
      ),
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          PopupMenuButton(
            onSelected: (c) {},
            child: Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(_currency),
                Icon(Icons.arrow_drop_down)
              ],
            ),
            itemBuilder: (context) => CURRENCY_CODES
                .map((c) => PopupMenuItem(value: c, child: Text(c)))
                .toList(),
          ),
          Flexible(
            child: TextFormField(),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```